# How to make boolean buttons in Android random?

Tags: android, button, random, boolean

I have four buttons and they are boolean - i want to make them different every time the image and the text inside them changes - i.e. once a button will be true, other time it will be false. How can this be done? Thank u !

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    startActivity(item.getIntent());
    return true;
}


public void onNoButton(View v) {
    handleAnswerAndShowNextQuestion(false);
}

public void onYesButton(View v) {
    handleAnswerAndShowNextQuestion(true);
}

private void handleAnswerAndShowNextQuestion(boolean bAnswer) {
    int curScore = mGameSettings.getInt(GAME_PREFERENCES_SCORE, 0);
    int nextQuestionNumber = mGameSettings.getInt(GAME_PREFERENCES_CURRENT_QUESTION, 1) + 1;

    Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
    editor.putInt(GAME_PREFERENCES_CURRENT_QUESTION, nextQuestionNumber);

    // Log the number of "yes" answers only
    if (bAnswer == true) {
        editor.putInt(GAME_PREFERENCES_SCORE, curScore + 1);
    }
    editor.commit();

    if (mQuestions.containsKey(nextQuestionNumber) == false) {
        // Load next batch
        try {
            loadQuestionBatch(nextQuestionNumber);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Loading updated question batch failed", e);
        }
    }

    if (mQuestions.containsKey(nextQuestionNumber) == true) {
        // Update question text
        TextSwitcher questionTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.TextSwitcher_QuestionText);
        questionTextSwitcher.setText(getQuestionText(nextQuestionNumber));

        // Update question image
        ImageSwitcher questionImageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.ImageSwitcher_QuestionImage);
        Drawable image = getQuestionImageDrawable(nextQuestionNumber);
        questionImageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(image);
    } else {
        // Tell the user we don't have any new questions at this time
        handleNoQuestions();
    }

}

  private void handleNoQuestions() {
    TextSwitcher questionTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.TextSwitcher_QuestionText);
    questionTextSwitcher.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.no_questions));
    ImageSwitcher questionImageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.ImageSwitcher_QuestionImage);
    questionImageSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.noquestion);

    // Disable yes button
    Button yesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_Yes);
    yesButton.setEnabled(false);

    // Disable no button
    Button noButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button_No);
    noButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: your question is not very clear. do you want your button to act as radio buttons?

like, user touches on them once and they get toggled (from yes to no, no to yes, true to false, false to true). like this?

Comment: yes if i got it right - once for example button1 is true, thne the next time its false , etc. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. Just create your environment (image and buttons) like normal. Assign your proper listeners for the buttons. Then create a new Random object. Get a random boolean. If the boolean == true, add the `true` button to your layout first, else add the `false` button.

```
public View getEnvironment(Context context) {
        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);

        ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
        image.setId(0);
        // Instantiate image (add image and listener is needed)
        Button truee = new Button(context);
        // Add event listener
        Button falsee = new Button(context);
        // Add event listener

        Random rand = new Random();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        image.setLayoutParams(lp);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams left = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 80);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 0);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams right = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 80);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 0);

        if (rand.nextBoolean()) {
            truee.setLayoutParams(left);
            falsee.setLayoutParams(right);
        } else {
            truee.setLayoutParams(right);
            falsee.setLayoutParams(left);
        }

        rl.addView(image);
        rl.addView(truee);
        rl.addView(falsee);

        return rl;
    }
```

### Edit:

I did not realise the OP was asking for a [CheckBox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) before posting. I will leave this up just in case someone wants it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. But isn't it that one button will stay always true and the other will be false all the time ?

Comment: Oh, you mean a <a href="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html">CheckBox</a>?

Comment: More like i have 2 buttons and sometimes i want button 1 to be true and sometimes false

Answer (score 0):

It's not wise to use buttons as radio buttons. Both are different, have different purposes and the idea is semantically wrong.

Skin your radio buttons as normal buttons.

Here is a good guide on skinning android

http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/